# character table of $2D_{8}(2)$

Tags: gr.group-theory

In my new research study I  need the character tables of  a simple group $^2D_8(2)$ and for that I was trying to find a reference and in this regard I came across a reference "Character degrees and their multiplicities for some groups of Lie type of rank < 9" with the link address "http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Frank.Luebeck/chev/DegMult/index.html?LANG=en"»Frank.Luebeck/Chev/DegMult, 2005".  Unfortunately, I could not find the character degrees of the group in that reference.

```
  I sent an email to the author, but I have not received an answer from him, yet. I wonder if you can help me to find out the irreducible character degrees of $^2D_8(2)$. Can you give me a reference for finding the degrees of irreducible characters of   $^2D_8(2)$?
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you looked in ATLAS?

Comment: @AHusain It is not in the ATLAS. This group is otherwise known as $\Omega^{-}(16,2)$.